# Java won't let me use multiple else statements

Tags: java

I've tried making it look identical to other pieces of code I've found online.
I've tried nesting it.
I've done most of what I thought would fix it.
I'm new to java. Can anyone help? Why won't it let me use two elses?

import java.util.Scanner;
public class FirstProgram {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a number>>>");
String Number1 = user_input.next();

System.out.print("Enter another number>>>");
String Number2 = user_input.next();
{
    if (Number1.equals(Number2))
        System.out.println("These numbers are equal");

 else if (Number1.compareTo(Number2) < 0);
    System.out.println(Number1 + " Is less than " + Number2);

    else if (Number1.compareTo(Number2) > 0);
        System.out.println(Number1 + " Is greater than " + Number2);

        }

}
```

}

Comment: Java is NOT JavaScript

Comment: You need to remove the semicolons after your if statements,

Comment: Thank you so much. I wouldve been looking for years

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the semicolons from the lines with the `else`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a number>>>");
String Number1 = user_input.next();

System.out.print("Enter another number>>>");
String Number2 = user_input.next();
{
    if (Number1.equals(Number2))
        System.out.println("These numbers are equal");
    else if (Number1.compareTo(Number2) < 0) // removed semicolon
        System.out.println(Number1 + " Is less than " + Number2);
    else if (Number1.compareTo(Number2) > 0) //removed semicolon
        System.out.println(Number1 + " Is greater than " + Number2);
}

}
```

I find that it's good practice to use braces, to help avoid mistakes like this.